# working with check box list

Tags: c#, winforms

hey i have a checkbox list , which inside it there are checkbox items ofc.
i am trying without succuess to understand how to open up an event which is being occured whenever a checkbox list is being checked
thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to remember that you have to use the CheckedListBox OnClick event.. In the eventhandler you find the selected checkbox, and check it's value.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> groups = new List<int>();
foreach (var item in clbGroup.CheckedItems)
{
    ListViewItem foundItem = listViewGroups.FindItemWithText(item.ToString(), false, 0, false);
    if (foundItem != null)
    {
        groups.Add(Convert.ToInt32(foundItem.Tag));
    }
}
```

I am saving all the checked items from the CheckBoxList `clbGroup` into groups `List<int>`.

Comment: there is an object called checkedboxlist why not using it ?

Comment: clbGroup is a checkedboxlist, my snippet shows you how you can get the items that are checked... foreach (var item in clbGroup.CheckedItems) does that...